# Electron Notification not displaying large images

Tags: javascript, notifications, electron

I'm trying to set up a notification in Electron (13.5.0), which we would like to have a large image display in some circumstances, similar to Netflix's show notifications, or [this example](https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/mddgSkoc6MYLRxJbCZYpGT-970-80.jpg.webp)

We're using HTML5's [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification) class, and while they generally seem to work, the (large) image property doesn't seem to.

I'm using this as a basic example:

main.js:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  console.log('create window')
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  win.loadFile('test.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

test.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <script src="renderer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.
  </body>
</html>
```

renderer.js:

```js
console.log(`test pre notification`)
const title = "notification title!"
const options = {
  body: "Here is a bunch of text that goes inside the body of the notification, so it mimicks what you might see with actual content.",
  image: "architecture-3095716_960_720.jpg",
  // icon: "architecture-3095716_960_720.jpg",
  silent: true
}
const noti = new Notification(title, options)
console.log(`test post notification`, noti.body, noti.image)
```

Of note:

- This is on Windows 10.
- We are running on Electron 13.5.0 (due to other issues with more recent updates)
- The notification works, just the large image doesn't seem to display, despite getting the url value out of the Notification(see the console log).
- The `image` url has been tested with an http/https link, as well as with a local copy of the .jpg (in the current example above). The `icon` property loads the image without problem, but the `image` property never seems to. The image we're using is within the listed bounds. The [Mozilla Notification documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification) seems to indicate that both [icon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/icon) and [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/image) follow the same requirements, so I'm not sure why there's discrepancy there.

How do I get the large image to display? What am I missing here?

EDIT:
I've also attempted to use Electron's [Main process Notification API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/notifications), which did not work either, and is why I posted this question.

Additionally, Netflix does display a large image in their notification when in Chrome, which indicates that the HTML Notification API should support them, even without requiring the use of Electron's Main process Notification API.

Comment: Electron has its own notification API.  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/notifications

Comment: I've attempted to test using that api as well already, which did not work, and is why I posted this question. 

Additionally, Netflix does display a large image in their notification, which indicates that the HTML Notification API should support them, even without requiring the use of Electron's Main process Notification API